# What processes are used by DRM?

Tags: macos, itunes, terminal, drm

Whenever some content is DRM-protected, screenshots of such content are masked. Even using Terminal does not avoid such problems.

Which processes in `ps ax` are used by DRM that is implemented by iTunes?

**EDIT:**
I posted this question originally on `Unix & Linux` with a bounty:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254325/what-processes-are-used-by-drm?noredirect=1#comment443851_254325

Comment: You need to read the comments on the original question and act on them. This is still too broad to answer, although the answer will probably be that it's not a separate process, for example iTunes DRM is implemented by iTunes itself. If you just want to know how a process can monitor another process, that's a different question.

Comment: @blm now it's only one concrete question... or still too broad?

Comment: Once you know which process it is (it any at all), what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: @patrix I hope to understand how it works

Comment: The "process" is called Protected Audio/Video Path (PAVP) and runs on a separate processor (Intel Management Engine) where you can't get at it. This processor decrypts the DRM data and writes it to protected memory to which the main processor has no access. The IME is real interesting and if you're interested check out [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kCICUPc9_8).